# How to setup Xcode automatic signing for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, apple-developer

I'm trying to finish up a small game I'm writing in Xcode for iOS.

I have a valid developer account and team setup and I've followed the simple procedure outlined here;

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html

But when I try to add Game Center capability in Xcode I get and error that states that I should "Add the Game Center feature to your App ID".

[Game Center Capability Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WuOQ.png)

But then there is no matching App ID in my developer Web site and I can't add it either as it complains that "An App ID (with my App ID) is not available".

Frustrating as hell, tips appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added your Apple Developer account to Xcode via the Xcode Preferences screen's Accounts tab?

[image]

If you have not added your account there, add it and then try switching the Game Center capability on and off for your project.

If you have added the account already, then try exiting Xcode and restarting it. Sometimes Xcode appears to get a bit "confused" after it has been running for a while and a simple restart seems to fix a lot of issues :)

If neither of the above helps, let me know and I'll try to help you figure out what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I also tried removing and re-adding the account as well, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried changing your bundle identifier to something else and then testing to see if you can add Game Center capability? If that works, then try changing your bundle ID back to your original bundle ID and try again.

Comment: Yeah, I even tried creating a separate project from scratch with a different App ID with pretty much the Sam results.

Comment: Strange. You do have Internet connectivity on that machine, right? Also, have you tried going into the Accounts tab in Preferences, selecting the team, and then selecting to "Manage Preferences" and then checking to see if there are any issues displayed there?

Comment: Everything else I use other than Xcode appears to work and nothing (including Xcode) has complained about connectivity to the internet. Worst of all the App ID specified in Xcode becomes unusable in Member Center, i.e. can't manually create an App ID with the same values as in Xcode.

Comment: And I take it that the App ID you use in Xcode does not appear in your Member Center when you log in via a browser? If so, and you are sure you are using the same account in both cases, you might want to contact Apple to see if perhaps they can help? I can take a look if you want as well, but since I'd actually need to see what is going on, this might not be something you want to trust to somebody off the Internet :)

Comment: Better be the same account, I only have one! ;)

Opened a bug in Bug Reporter, now we wait the mandatory period.